What is the X;P-ordered form of $P^k X^k$?
By repetitively applying the commutation relation $PX = XP - i$, we can in principle get the X;P-ordered form of $P^k X^k$, where all $X$'s are to the left hand side of $P$'s.
However, after fooling around myself, I have only noted that $P^k X^k = (XP-i)(XP-2i)\cdots(XP-ki)$ and $X^kP^k = XP(XP + i)(XP + 2i)\cdots(XP+(k-1)i)$, which is not I wanted.
Is there a nice procedure to arrive at the X;P-ordered form of $P^k X^k$?

Virtual Duplicate.

Linked.

@CosmasZachos Thanks. I guess one can replace $a$ with $X$ and $a^\dagger$ with $-iP$.

Indeed, that should do it. Alternatively, you might also replace X with x and P with $\partial_x$.

Tiny addition: don't just replace, make sure you use the correct BCH identity where one exponential is displacement in x and the other in p

@QuantumMechanic I think we can replace simply because $[x, -ip] = 1 = [a, a^\dagger]$. Whatever applies to the pair $(a, a^\dagger)$ should also apply to pair $(x, -ip)$, as all that matters in the BCH formula is just the commutator.

Oh great, I didn't notice the $-i$
